# Ubuntu 13.10 Freeze Problem when maximizing window

Tags: unity

It doesn't happen always. I've been using Ubuntu 13.10 for few months now- and have been noticing this problem last few weeks only. Sometimes when I try to maximize a window by dragging it to the top edge of screen- I get a freeze. The only thing that moves is the cursor- and I have to hard restart my laptop by long-pressing power button- which damages the hard-drive everytime -_- Can I get a fix to this please??

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in compiz: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1244754 which will be fixed in 14.04. Here's what I do when it happens:

1. Switch to virtual console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>)
2. Log in with your credentials
3. type `unity --replace` to restart unity
4. Switch back to the graphical interface by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

PS: in the bug report they mention that it's safer to maximize windows via key combination or the icon in the top left of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> prevents the lock up from occurring until reboot.

- [compiz freezes when dragging a window to the top bar after being semi-maximized](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1244754)

> I've finally found the condition that causes this issue.
>
> 1. Window geometry when it opens has the top decoration snapped to the panel and the bottom of the window is snapped to the bottom of the
>      screen.
> 2. Vertically semi-maximize the window by dragging the window to the left or right side of the screen.
> 3. Drag the window to the top to maximize the window.
>
> It's important to note the initial window geometry and the dragging to
>   semi-maximize. If either the top of the window is not snapped or the
>   bottom of the window is snapped, the issue does not occur. Also, using
>   the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> to vertically semi-maximize will avoid this
>   issue as well.

I have the same issue in compiz 9.10.2, It has been fixed in version 9.11.

> This bug was fixed in the package compiz -
>   1:0.9.11+14.04.20140214-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47950494/Force_Quit.desktop
mv Force_Quit.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Now search the dash for "Force Quit".
On clicking, you get a cross.just click the cross on the freezed window.But again,opening the dash can be a problem,in your case.

Comment: Yup- opening the dash is impossible while the whole desktop/keyboard is frozen

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes/36717#36717

Comment: Ohhhh. Very interesting!! Thanks. Although I cannot try this now- I'd have to wait till the problem reproduces itself- and then I will give it a shot. Let's see

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around with this problem safely by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> which will bring you to a terminal/console window then do a `sudo reboot` using your credentials. It happens to me randomly as well and can get annoying. I am not sure why this problem hasn't been fixed by now.